# Sentiment analysis web application printing results to html page using django

Tags: python, django

I am new to stackflow and had a question about my code. For a little background, I am creating a sentiment analysis web application for a class. I am using python's textblob to perform the analysis and will be displaying the output to the user through a HTML/CSS webpage. I am using Django as the web frame work for this project.

My issue is displaying that result from the python analysis into our results.html webpage. We have a views.py that has call_command("analysis") that calls to run the python analysis, then saves the output in a variable called sentiment.

#### views.py

```
def results(request):
    sentiment = call_command('analysis')
    context = {'sentiment': sentiment}
    return render(request, 'sawa/results.html', context)
```

We are trying to print the contents within that variable to the webpage. Below is how we tried

#### results.html

```
<section>
    <form>
        <fieldset>

            <!-- RESULTS WILL BE POSTED HERE -->
            
            <p>{{sentiment}}</p>

            <p>RESULTS WILL BE POSTED HERE</p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</section>
```

We used the `{{sentiment}}` to try and print the results. However, when loading the webpage the only thing that prints is "None". We have tested the analysis separately and have gotten results, so it can't be that there are no results.

Comment: Can you print a expected output of `sentiment`? Try to add `print sentiment` after `sentiment = call_command('analysis')`. And paste here the result you get.

Comment: the return type of `call_command` function is either None or doesnt returns anything. Please share the code so we can provide more help on it.

Comment: Tarun Behal - the call_command function we are using is a prepackaged django function. It is meant to call and run our analysis.py code to perform the analysis.

Comment: Manish Gupta - we tried adding print sentiment after the sentiment = call_command('analysis') and it did not work. the results we expect to get displayed are: Total number of reviews =  662
Number of Terrible reviews =  2
Number of Bad reviews =  30
Number of Neutral reviews =  5
Number of Good reviews =  577
Number of Excellent reviews =  48
Percentage of Terrible reviews =  0.30%
Percentage of Bad reviews =  4.53%
Percentage of Neutral reviews =  0.76%
Percentage of Good reviews =  87.16%
Percentage of Excellent reviews =  7.25%